# Difference between "illusion" and "delusion"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, negation, medical

Can somebody please elaborate on the difference between *illusion* and *delusion*? Especially in medical terms.

Comment: @downvoter : why the downvote ?? If there is a downvote ,there has to be an explanation explaining , WHY ??

Comment: Could you post the definitions from the dictionaries you have checked, and explain your difficulty in more detail, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position is not as simple as David Schwartz makes it sound.

There is no reason why an 'illusion' should not be peculiar to one individual. There is nothing inherent in its meaning which says it has to be something which everyone who comes into contact with the circumstances has.

Indeed the ODE splits the meaning into two parts, the first which is more associated with a single individual's perceptions, ('he held an illusion of family disharmony, which was not apparent to all') the second as a misinterpreted sensory experience generally (e.g.the pencil in the water).

'Delusion' is a deeper and more serious instance of the first type of illusion, and can (though not always) be a symptom of a mental disorder.

Answer (score 2):

Illusions have physical causes outside of the people experiencing them and are experienced by all human beings under the same external circumstances. Delusions have psychological causes are are experienced by particular human beings due to their internal circumstances.

Everyone sees a straight pencil as crooked if it is half immersed in water. This is an illusion. But if your Aunt thinks the Nazis are trying to poison her oatmeal, that's a delusion.

Comment: 10 people enter a dark room , they saw a rope , and only one thought it was a snake , its an illusion , right ?

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Neither. That's just an incorrect conclusion drawn from limited information.

Comment: *Probably* a delusion, depending on what your aunt did in the war.